# HydratedBloc produces inconsistent results between two BloCs with identical code

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

So I am writing a todo list application, which contains both Tasks and Habits. These are state managed and persisted between runs using HydratedBloc. As such, I have the following two BloCs:

````dart
class TasksBloc extends HydratedBloc<TasksEvent, TasksState> {
  TasksBloc() : super(TasksInitial()) {
    on<LoadTasks>(_onLoadTasks);
    on<AddTask>(_onAddTask);
    on<UpdateTask>(_onUpdateTask);
    on<DeleteTask>(_onDeleteTask);
    on<ToggleTaskDone>(_onToggleTaskDone);
  }
  
  _onLoadTasks(LoadTasks event, Emitter<TasksState> emit) {
    /// Manual typecasting to resolve strange runtime type error:
    /// type '_Map<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
    /// this manual typecasting is not necessary for the identical code in _onLoadHabits()
    ///
    /// ```dart
    /// Map<String, dynamic> habitsJson = HydratedBloc.storage.read('HabitsBloc');
    /// HabitsLoaded habitsState = fromJson(habitsJson) as HabitsLoaded;
    /// emit(habitsState);
    /// ```
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> tasksPreJson = HydratedBloc.storage.read('TasksBloc');
    Map<String, dynamic> tasksJson = tasksPreJson.map(
      (key, value) => MapEntry(key.toString(), value),
    );
    TasksLoaded habitsState = fromJson(tasksJson) as TasksLoaded;
    emit(habitsState);
  }
  ...
}
````

```dart
abstract class TasksState extends Equatable {
  final List<Task> tasks;
  const TasksState() : tasks = const [];

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [tasks];
}

class TasksInitial extends TasksState {
  final List<Task> tasks;
  TasksInitial() : tasks = data.tasks; // a hard coded list of Tasks
  get props => [tasks];
}

class TasksLoaded extends TasksState {
  final List<Task> tasks;
  TasksLoaded(this.tasks);
  get props => [tasks];
}
```

and:

```dart
class HabitsBloc extends HydratedBloc<HabitsEvent, HabitsState> {
  HabitsBloc() : super(HabitsInitial()) {
    on<LoadHabits>(_onLoadHabits);
    on<AddHabit>(_onAddHabit);
    on<DeleteHabit>(_onDeleteHabit);
    on<UpdateHabit>(_onUpdateHabit);
    on<ResetAllHabits>(_onResetAllHabits);
    on<ToggleHabitDoneToday>(_onToggleHabit);
  }
  
  void _onLoadHabits(LoadHabits event, Emitter<HabitsState> emit) {
    Map<String, dynamic> habitsJson = HydratedBloc.storage.read('HabitsBloc');
    HabitsLoaded habitsState = fromJson(habitsJson) as HabitsLoaded;
    emit(habitsState);
  }
  ...
}
```

```dart
abstract class HabitsState extends Equatable {
  final List<Habit> habits;
  const HabitsState() : habits = const [];

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [habits];
}

class HabitsInitial extends HabitsState {
  final List<Habit> habits;
  HabitsInitial() : habits = data.habits; // a hard coded list of Habits
  get props => [habits];
}

class HabitsLoaded extends HabitsState {
  final List<Habit> habits;
  HabitsLoaded(this.habits);
  get props => [habits];
}
```

finally, my BloCs are initialized as follows:

```dart
class _AchieverAppState extends State<AchieverApp> {
  HabitsBloc habitsBloc = HabitsBloc()..add(LoadHabits());
  TasksBloc tasksBloc = TasksBloc()..add(LoadTasks());
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var brightness = MediaQuery.platformBrightnessOf(context);
    var theme = AppTheme(brightness);
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      systemNavigationBarColor: theme.backgroundColor,
    ));
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<HabitsBloc>(
          create: (_) => habitsBloc,
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => tasksBloc,
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
      ...
```

The inconsistencies I'm experiencing are twofold, but might be related:

1. As can be seen in _onLoadTasks / `_onLoadHabits`, I get a type error when `_onLoadTasks` attempts to call `read()` on `HydratedBloc.storage`. I initially began with identical code between Tasks/Habits, but had to add an additional step to manually typecast the result when loading tasks from storage.
2. On the first application run (uninstall+fresh install), HabitsBloc successfully loads it's initial state. However, despite being written identically, TasksBloc does not, and instead tells me that it can't convert type `null` to type `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`. However, after closing and re-opening the app, the initial state has been successfully written to storage and is restored and loaded.

---

So, #1 is weird, but I found a work around with an extra step, as can be seen above. I don't understand why the behavior is not identical between the two Blocs, but this issue is low priority. However, #2 is high priority, as it results in the default tasks not loading correctly after install.

From what I can see, there is a different order of operations occurring between the two BloC initializations:

- In the case of HabitsBloc, the HabitsInitial state is initialized, serialized and stored to hive, thus when storage.read() is called, it successfully returns.
- In the case of TasksBloc, the storage.read() call is happening before the TasksInitial state is serialized and written to disk, thus a null result is returned from storage.read()

---

Debugging:

- breakpoints placed at:

  1. HabitsInitial constructor,
  2. TasksInitial constructor,
  3. first line of _onLoadHabits()
  4. first line of _onLoadTasks()
- can see that:

  - as expected, HabitsInitial() TasksInitial() constructors called before _onLoad methods
  - lists of Habits and Tasks are successfully retrieved from data, stored in lists in their respective initial state classes
  - when _onLoadHabits called (first _onLoad call) I inspect HydratedBloc.storage._box.values. This contains the following json:

```json
_ValueIterable ((Frame(key: HabitsBloc, value: {habits: [{"id":"00ca4db1-c2cd-4d72-8e96-79087acc10aa","title":"Brush your teeth","doneDays":[false,false,false,false,false,false,false]},{"id":"8647b4ba-73e4-4889-ad96-771c1a30e0dc","title":"Read a book","doneDays":[false,false,false,false,false,false,false]}]}, length: 293, offset: -1)))
```

This tells me that HydratedBloc serialized and stored `HabitsInitial`, but that for some reason `TasksInitial` was not stored into HydratedBloc storage before the _onLoad event handler is called.

**NOTE:** remember that `TasksInitial` does get stored at some point, because on the second time the application is run, the `HydratedBloc.storage._box.values` contains both `HabitsBloc` and `TasksBloc`, and the values which could not be loaded on first app run are loaded correctly.

This behavior can be reproduced every time the app is uninstalled and reinstalled, demonstrating that HabitsBloc and TasksBloc both individually have consistent behavior between runs. The inconsistency is between the two BloCs, which has me completely stymied.

github repo:
https://github.com/imclerran/achiever_app/tree/persist-app-state